# Failed to connect to dumpstate service: No such file or directory

Tags: android, runtime.exec, dumpsys

I try to run bugreport from Runtime exec and I get the following error:

```
FAIL:Failed to connect to dumpstate service: No such file or directory
```

I looked into bugreport code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/master/cmds/bugreport/bugreport.cpp) , and it looks like it failed to open a tcp socket to dumpstate service. I also investigated that when com.android.settings asks for a bugreport it uses ActivityManagerService function "requestBugReport" as you can see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/4f868ed/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java), the system set property to start a service but I fail to that also. I tried to reflect this method but for some reason this "ActivityManagerService" class not found.

```
 val check = Class
        .forName("com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService")
        .getMethod("requestBugReport")
        .invoke(null)
```

Is there anyway to get the output of bugreport/bugreportz?

Comment: Hi Zach, did you managed to fix this error? I'm having the same problem, and the internet seems to be not aware of this problem. Except this post.

Comment: That's possibly a permissions issue, only shell,system and sometimes root can execute bugreport

Answer (score 0):

you may need the "android.os.BugreportManager" class provided by google android sdk.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which [a comment should be used instead of an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173)). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."